# Why can't ODE's be solved only using algebra?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving a differential equation, why can't you only use algebra and integration to solve it?
For example

$x dx + (y - 2x)dy = 0$
$x dx=-(y-2x)dy$
$\int x dx = \int -y+2x dy$
$\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{-y^2}{2}+2xy+C$
Is this technically a solution a solution to the ODE but since it's not explicit it's not a very good one? Why is it necessary to use a more advance technique like substitution?

Comment: There are in fact some differential equations where you can do something like that, they are called [separable differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: @Eff that was my line of thought: I went to my text book into a section that required substitution to solve and I thought to myself "what would happen if I tried to force using separation of variables?"

Comment: @Eff under what circumstances can you use separation of variables? Why can't it be used here?

Comment: Laplace transforms can make solving certain ODEs into solving roots of polynomials. Which is strictly algebra, and the Laplace transform is an integral. The problem is that solving roots of polynomials is extremely hard in general, and not all equations of interest are even nice enough to give these polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that
$$\int -y +2x dy \neq \frac{-y^2}{2} +2xy+C$$
is that $x$ is not a constant. It's a variable - which is what makes the ODE so useful!

Comment: Ok, so when you differentiate with respect to a variable you could hold a variable constant but it doesn't work for integration? For example let $y=f(x, t)=x^2+t^2$. Then $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=2x$ but you're saying $\int x^2+t^2 dx \neq \frac{x^3}{3}+t^2x+C$?

Comment: @Celeritas I'm not sure. I haven't taken multivariable calculus yet, so I only know the rules for partial derivatives. This, though, isn't a PDE, so I don't think the rules of multivariable calculus apply.

Comment: The issue is that x and y are not independent variables.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip ok, but in my example $\int x^2+t^2 dx =\frac{x^3}{3}+t^2x+C$ because x and t are independent of each other? (not I replaced the not equals with equals)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip so you're saying HDE's answer is wrong because x not being a constant is not the problem?

Comment: @Celeritas: no, I'm saying HDE is right. In your example of $f(x,t)$ , $x$ and $t$ are independent, so what you did is correct, but the situation of the ODE is different.

Comment: More precisely, it's certainly not a solution by taking the differential. In particular, $d(xy)=ydx+xdy$, but the OP has forgotten the $ydx$ term.