# Why is it sometimes it seems like you can integrate with respect to x or y and treat the other as a constant, and other times you can't?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am very confused right now. I thought we [can't just do algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024990/why-cant-odes-be-solved-only-using-algebra) on an ODE to find the solution. The following isn't allowed:

$x dx + (y - 2x)dy = 0$
$x dx=-(y-2x)dy$
$\int x dx = \int -y+2x dy$
$\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{-y^2}{2}+2xy+C$

But it sure seems like we do just that when we're solving an exact equation. For example
$(2xy^2-3)dx+(2x^2y+4)dy=0$
Let $M(x,y)=2xy^2-3, N(x,y)=2x^2y+4$
Then $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=4xy=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ so the equation is exact.
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xy^2-3$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2x^2y+4$
Integrating to find f $\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx = \int (2xy^2-3)dx = 2x^2y^2-3x+g(y)$

Aren't we contradicting ourselves because now we can integrate $y$ with respect to x no problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, $y$ is an unknown function of $x$ (and you are integrating with respect to $x$). In principle, you could "compute" $\int y\,dx$ but the result will be an anti-derivative of $y$, not just $xy$. Of course, since $y$ is unknown, we can't write down its anti-derivative directly.

In the second case, $f$ is a function of *two* variables, $x$ and $y$ and you are integrating with respect to one of them.

Comment: ugh not getting it. "In the second case, f is a function of two variables, x and y" I thought the solution of an ODE is always a function of 2 variables: $x$ and $y$

Comment: @Celeritas Solving an exact equation, you're looking for a solution of the type: "$f(x,y) = C$", which defines $y$ *implictly* in terms of $x$ or vice versa. Usually when you are solving an ODE you are looking for an *explicit* solution $y(x)$.

Comment: @mrf I'm very uncertain about the idea that $y$ can be understood to be an independent variable, despite the observation that the solution process yields an implicit function.  The derivation of the form $M(x,\ y)\ dx + N(x,\ y)\ dy = 0$ relies on taking the total derivative of $f(x,\ y(x))$, not $f(x,\ y)$.